# Convert Markdown to PDF with Pandoc Using SFFMS

Tags: pdf, markdown, pandoc

I'm hoping to be able to use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert my stories from Markdown to PDF files, formatted using [sffms](http://www.mcdemarco.net/sffms/). I've tried a few things, but so far, no joy. I'm fairly comfortable with the command line, but LaTeX is new to me.

Here's what I've done so far.

1. I installed Pandoc v. 1.13.2
2. In pandoc's default user directory, I created a folder, `templates`
3. In that folder, I installed `mytemplate.tex` from [the example](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demo/mytemplate.tex) as well as [the other default templates](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates)
4. Also in that folder, I have installed the files needed for sffms, being careful to run the install command `latex sffms.ins`

My Markdown file, `sample.md` looks like this:

```
---  
title: Document Title 
author: Firstname Lastname
date: 2015-01-24
---      


# Section 1  

## Subsection 1.1  
Lorem *ipsum* dolor sit amet, **consectetur** adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque  ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.

## Subsection 1.2    

# Section 2    

# Section 3    

A sentence that needs a note.[ˆ1]     

[ˆ1]: my first footnote! And a [link](https://www.eff.org/)
```

When I use the following, Pandoc is able to create a PDF using the default document class:

```
pandoc --standalone --smart sample.md -o manuscript.pdf
```

Next, I attempted to add the variable to indicate the document class...

```
pandoc --standalone --smart --variable documentclass=sffms sample.md -o manuscript.pdf
```

...but that resulted in the following error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \UL@on was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.56
```

The trouble seems to be that sffms doesn't support section headings. If I use a different document class, that does support section headings, then everything works as expected.

Is it possible to use sffms, even though the markdown file has subheadings, without getting an error?

Comment: Can you render the pdf without any extra options?

Comment: Yes, if I do something like 
``pandoc sample.md -o plaintest.pdf``
it makes a PDF just fine, but of course the formatting is default.

Comment: Can you please post a small example input which shows the problem and a minimal command which causes the error.

Comment: I'm not sure the error was relevant, so I've revised my question down to what I hope are the bare essentials.

Comment: To debug, you can use `pandoc --standalone --smart --variable documentclass=sffms sample.md -o manuscript.tex` to generate a .tex, then look at that to see what's wrong with it and try to make a pdf from it with `pdflatex manuscript.tex`

Comment: The trouble seems to be that sffms doesn't support section headings. If I use a different document class, that does support section headings, then everything works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the sffms document doesn't have support for sections, subsections and their associated subheadings. The author may add support for this in a future version.

Until then, one answer to this would be to use a different document class. I've sketched up [a Pandoc template that give more-or-less analogous formatting](https://gist.github.com/dylan-k/c596ca65098ac3f61ce2) via the scrartcl document class. It's probably sloppy, being a first attempt, but it works, mostly.